# Cannot call php delete from database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to javascript and ajax, I want to call php file which deletes the selected row from Mysql database in a javascript file so I tried to explore the answers I found here concerning this question but I couldn't resolve it, here is the php file called delete-consultation.php:

```
<?php
global $db;
$idconsult=$_POST['del_id'];

   
    $q = $db->prepare(
        'DELETE FROM consultation
        WHERE id_consultation = :idc');

    $q->bindValue(':idc', (int)$idconsult , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->execute();
```

And here is how I tried to call it using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "delete-consultation.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data:{
                del_id: rows[0]
            },
            success: function(){
                console.log("true");
            }
        });
```

I am getting 200 ok as a response but always without the id paraleter and the delete operation is not being executed, am I missing anything? Any advice could help, thanks

Comment: 1. Does the deletion code work outside of ajax? 2. Why is your ajax code calling  "delete-consultation **.html**" ?

Comment: the deletion code is working outside of ajax, and the the ajax code is calling a php file I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have a **.php** file, so why is your ajax code calling a **.html** file?

Comment: I edited the question, I am calling a php file in the ajax code, it was a typo when I wrote the question here.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$rows[0]` has the correct value, that is is being passed in to the deletion code correctly, and that the `$db` variable is accessible and in your deletion code?

Comment: @MRSkan What is you `console.log` shows up as  "true" ? Also make sure you are passing the correct `del_id`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I just wanted to test if there is a success or not, the del_id is correct.

Comment: Well then, can you show us the results please? We don't know your set up and can't run your code, so we depend entirely on what you tell us to be able to help! Can you show us the results of `var_dump(rows[0]);` in the main code and `var_dump($idconsult); var_dump($q);` in the deletion code

Comment: @MRSkan Yes you did off-course.  We are trying our best to help you out with different scenrios to debug the code. Please follow @ FLuffyKitten comment and see what you get.

Comment: no worries guys, thanks for ur time,I did it using another idea, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by editing the ajax code like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "delete-consultation.html",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            datas:{
                del_id: rows[0]
            },
            success: function(){
                console.log("true");
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("false");
            }
        });
```

and the php code was correct actually what was wrong is the word 'data' changed to be 'datas':

Comment: Happy to know that